# How to fix "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'cleanup' is a 'let' constant" error?

Tags: swift

Here I am trying to add a user's username to the list of users in a Cleanup object. I tried adding inout, but it returns another error saying "cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'cleanup' is a 'let' constant" at where I call the function.

//this is the function

```
func joinCleanup(user: BBPBUser, cleanup: Cleanup){
  
    do {
        cleanup.users.append(user.username) //here is where the error occurs
        try db.collection("Cleanups").document(cleanup.username).updateData(["users" : cleanup.users])
        currCleanup = cleanup
    }
    catch {
        self.errorMessage = "Error joining cleanup."
    }
}
```

//this is where I call it (this is in a view)

```
let currCleanup: Cleanup?
let currUser: BBPBUser?


if let cleanup = self.currCleanup, let user = self.currUser {

        Button {
            cleanupsManager.joinCleanup(user: user, cleanup: cleanup)          
        }
}
```

Comment: This is SwitUI, is it? Then better read how `@State` works. It would be also helpful to add your definition of `Cleanup`.

Comment: Every parameter you have in a function is `let` declared unless you specifically declare it using `inout`

Comment: If you don't understand the difference between `var`, `let`, `@State var` etc... then you really need to 
read the basics at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html 
and do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  There is no short cuts, you have to know the basics first, before you code an App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others, by default parameters are passed to functions as read-only let constants. You need to add the `inout` label to a parameter if you want to pass it by reference and be able to change its value in the called function:

```
func joinCleanup(user: BBPBUser, cleanup: inout Cleanup){
    // Your code here
}
```

Then when you call it you need to prefix the variable with an `&` to indicate that you are passing it by reference:

```
var aCleanup = Cleanuup() // Replace with your code to create a `Cleanup` obj. This must be a `var`, not a `let` constant.

joinCleanup(user: aUser, cleanup: &aCleanup) // Note the `&`
```

Comment: And note that having a function change the values of it's parameters is not great practice. It's better to write your functions to take read-only inputs and return the output as the function results.